# OpenGL not rendering points clicked by users

Tags: c++, opengl

The basic premise of my application (as of now) is just to render the points clicked by the user. This is the code I have (in snippets - I'll try to add my "train of thought" if that can help):

First the User clicks wherever he wants the points to be displayed (after the initialization of the window):

```
  void mouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow* _window, int button, int action, int mods)
{
     switch (button)
   {
    case GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
    if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
    {
        if (transitionalFlag == false) {


            glfwGetCursorPos(window, &x, &y);
            setPositionVector(x, y);
            flag = true;
        }
        else { //please ignore the else for the moment seeing as I can't get the first one to work

            glfwGetCursorPos(window, &x, &y);
            setPositionVector(x, y);
            pointsClickedByUserTranslational.push_back(positionsClickedByUser);
        }

    }

  }
}
```

So whenever I have to take my first line I go to transitional and take the x and y of my cursor into setPositionVector ( which is the following method):

```
void setPositionVector(double xpos, double ypos) {
    if (transitionalFlag == false) {
         positionsClickedByUser = windowToWorldCoords(glm::vec2(x, y));
         vectorsToFloat(positionsClickedByUser);
         updatePointsVBO();
}
   else {
       positionsClickedByUser = glm::vec3(xpos, ypos, 0);
       vectorsToFloat(positionsClickedByUser);
       updatePointsVBO();
  }
}
```

This method takes in the x and y and first changes it up to my world coordinate ( which is the following method) :

```
glm::vec3 windowToWorldCoords(const glm::vec2 p)
{
// Get window dimensions
   int w, h;
   glfwGetWindowSize(window, &w, &h);

// Transform to camera coordinates; we assume the z-coordinate to be 0
   const GLfloat cameraX = 2 * p.x / w - 1;
   const GLfloat cameraY = -(2 * p.y / h - 1);

// Transform to world coordinates by inverting the transformation matrix
   return glm::vec3(glm::inverse(transformationMatrix) * glm::vec4(cameraX,         cameraY, 0.0f, 1.0f));
}
```

Which in returns a vec3 that I then change to float in this method:

```
 void vectorsToFloat(glm::vec3 vector) {

      vectorOfVertices.push_back(vector.x);
      vectorOfVertices.push_back(vector.y);
       vectorOfVertices.push_back(vector.z);

}
```

Afterwards, I have my updateVBO() method which is suppose to, well as it says, update my VBO everytime the user clicks on the screen

```
void  updatePointsVBO()
{
    glBindVertexArray(pointsVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointsVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    if (vectorOfVertices.size() > 0)
    {
       glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vectorOfVertices[0]) *      vectorOfVertices.size(), &vectorOfVertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

   }

  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

So all this is done in that order ( user clicks --> get cursor pos --> set my position Vector --> and lastly update my VBO with the new info)

In my main loop I got this:

```
int main() {


   initializeOpenGL();

   shader_program = shadersInitialization("vertex.shader", "fragment.shader");

   //linke your matrices to your shader
   modelMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "modelMatrix");
   projectionMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "projectionMatrix");
   viewMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "viewMatrix");




   //Function allows to set camera to look at object
   modelMatrix = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraTarget, upVector);


  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

      glfwPollEvents();



       glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


       glUseProgram(shader_program);
       //projMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, (float)WIDTH/(float)HEIGHT, 0.1f, 1000.0f );


       glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix));
       glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(viewMatrix));
       glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projectionMatrix));

      draw();


      glfwSwapBuffers(window);
   }


   glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &pointsVAO);
   glDeleteBuffers(1, &pointsVBO);

   glfwTerminate();
   return 0;
}
```

My draw function:

```
 void draw()
{
  glGenBuffers(1, &pointsVBO);
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &pointsVAO);

  glBindVertexArray(pointsVAO);
  glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vectorOfVertices.size());
 }
```

I'm not getting any error, just a blank screen. Also, I'm pretty sure my code isn't optimal the way it's coded right now, though I'd just like some pointers on how to make those points appear. Any would help.

Thanks!

Note: Please, if you're going to down vote this post, please indicate what I did wrong so my next question fits more the style wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new buffer generated and used in every call of the draw method. Since you upload data to such a buffer, then throw it away and generate a new buffer, you always draw with an empty buffer. You should move the object generation outside of the render loop.

In addition, only the last `pointsVBO` and `pointsVAO` get deleted at the moment. You should read a bit about which functions belong to initialization code and should only be called once (like `glGenVertexArrays`, `glVertexAttribPointer`, `glVertexAttribPointer`) and should be called only once and which functions have to be called every frame.

Comment: Ah I see, so would keeping only my glBuffer and glBufferData make it so that I can only update my VBO?

Comment: If you mean `glBindBuffer` and `glBufferData`, then yes: This is everything needed to update a buffer object. `glBufferSubData` would be even better (if the size of the buffer doesn't change) because it will override the buffer instead of allocating new memory.

Comment: Mhm weirdly, taking my binding those methods on outside of my rendering loop isn't doing anything. How else can I go about debugging this?